# Удаление товара из корзины

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Я реализовал удаление товара из корзины.

html форма

```
<h2>Корзина</h2>
<div><h2>Корзина</h2></div>
<div>

<?php foreach ($basket as $item) : ?>
    <p>Наименование: <?= $item['catalog_name'] ?>
        Цена: <?= $item['catalog_price'] ?>
        <button class="delete_fromBasket" data-basket_id="<?= $item['basket_id'] ?>" >Удалить из корзины</button><hr>
    </p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

js файл

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.delete_fromBasket').click(function(e){
        var basket_id = $(this).data('basket_id');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?c=Basket&act=deleteFromBasket', // куда отправляем
            type: "post", // метод передачи
            dataType: "json", // тип передачи данных
            data: { // что отправляем
                "basket_id":   basket_id
            },
               // после получения ответа сервера
            success: function(data){
                if(data.result == "success"){
                    alert('Товар успешно удален из корзины');
                }else{
                    alert('Произошла ошибки при удалении товара!');
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Все работает, но как мне сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки "Удалить из корзины", помимо сообщения об успешном удалении, еще и строка с этим товаром тоже пропадала из корзины?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.delete_fromBasket').click(function(e){
    var basket_id = $(this).data('basket_id');
    var button = this;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?c=Basket&act=deleteFromBasket', // куда отправляем
        type: "post", // метод передачи
        dataType: "json", // тип передачи данных
        data: { // что отправляем
            "basket_id":   basket_id
        },
           // после получения ответа сервера
        success: function(data){
            if(data.result == "success"){
                $(button).closest('p').remove();               // <--
                alert('Товар успешно удален из корзины');
            }else{
                alert('Произошла ошибки при удалении товара!');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: работает, спасибо=)